# WHM Pdo extension installation from php config

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

Can anyone help me on how to install the pdo mysql extension from whm. i rebuilt the server and installed it from apache update but it doesn't work. i get the below error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/mercygirlsschool/public_html/eduportal/schooloffice/MySqlExcelBuilder.class.php on line 40
```

Comment: after Apache rebuild it will work

Answer (score 1):

Apache uses the system PHP, which you will find here:

```
/usr/bin/php
/usr/local/bin/php
/usr/local/apache/modules/libphp5.so
```

To enable PDO in the system PHP:

1. Login to WHM
2. Click Apache Update
3. Click Start Customizing Based on Profile
4. Select an Apache version
5. Click Next Step
6. Select PHP 5
7. Click Next Step
8. Select a version of PHP 5
9. Click Next Step
10. Click Exhaustive Options List button
11. Scroll down to the check box labeled PDO
12. Click Save and Build

Src: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/enable-pdo-78853.html

Answer (score 0):

+1 to above answer and you can follow as well if wanted to install from Putty...

Enabling PDO in the system using Putty:

Login to Server

Run command as **/scripts/easyapache**

```
Select an Apache version

      Click Next Step
      Select a version of PHP 5
      Click Next Step
      Click Exhaustive Options List button
      Scroll down to the check box labeled PDO
      Click Save and Build
```